# Unable to view JSON response body in Postman which is present in console test

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I've setup a resource in API Gateway with an API key and a Mock Integration.  When I test in the console, I can see the canned JSON response which I setup in the integraion response.

However, when I test externally using Postman, I can see the expected status code in the response (201) but the response body is empty.

Would anyone be able to shed some light over why this might be?

Many thanks

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure, did you deploy the latest version of your API? I used the sample API below which worked fine for me. Could you try this one?

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "2016-04-19T19:54:16Z",
    "title": "my-mock-api"
  },
  "basePath": "/prod",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/": {
      "get": {
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "200 response",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Empty"
            }
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
          "responses": {
            "default": {
              "statusCode": "200",
              "responseTemplates": {
                "application/json": "{\"test\":\"test\"}"
              }
            }
          },
          "requestTemplates": {
            "application/json": "{\"statusCode\": 200}"
          },
          "type": "mock"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Empty": {
      "type": "object"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep - you were right.  I had forgotten to deploy the latest version.  Thanks